# A small pattern in the primes. What can we do to continue the pattern ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, pattern-recognition

The pattern seems to have to do with divisors of the number $n$ or $n-1$.

$$
\begin{matrix}
p(1) & = 2 \\
p(2) & = 3 \\
p(3) & = 5 \\
p(4) & = 7 & = p(3) + (p(3) - p(2))\\
p(5) & = 11 & = p(4) + (p(2)^2 - p(3)) \\
p(6) & = 13 & = p(5) + (p(5) - p(2)^2) \\
p(7) & = 17 & = p(6) + (p(2)p(3) - p(5)) \\
p(8) & = 19 & = p(7) + (p(7) - p(2)p(3)) \\
p(9) & = 23 & = p(8) + (p(2)p(4) - p(7))\\
p(10) & = 29 & = p(9) + (p(3)^2 - p(2)p(4)) \\
p(11) & = \text{here the rule mysteriously ends}
\end{matrix}
$$

Any idea of how to generalize the rule so that it extends further than $p(11)$, where $p(n)$ is the $n$th prime number in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's very unclear what pattern you're picking up in this data; this feels to me a lot like the strong law of small numbers. e.g., you can write $p(11) = p(10)+(p(6)-p(5))$ or any of a bunch of different things, but there's nothing _natural_ about it.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  The data seems to be $p(n) = p(n-1) + c(n-1)$ where $c(n-1) = p(a)p(b) - p(c)p(d)$ where $n-1 = ab, n-2 = cd$ are nontrivial factorizations, otherwise use $c(n-1) = p(n-1) - p(c)p(d)$ and so on...

Comment: I was thinking of adding terms to the sum, but it's not easy to figure out what to do.  A computer program could do a much nicer jerb.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - that _does_ actually help explain what specifically you were seeing.  Unfortunately, I think it also makes it that much more likely that you're seeing small numbers at work, because it just so happens that when a lot of the terms of the form $p(n)-p(n-1)$ are 2 or 4, and lots of your $n$ factor into similar-ish numbers, you're going to see a lot of these sorts of coincidences.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki the pattern also happens to stop precisely after both $n-1, n-2$ are both reducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what rule you want here, that $p(n) = p(n - 1) + (\prod p(i) - \prod p(j))$? I think this would just follow from the fundamental theorem of arithemtic: $p(n) - p(n - 1)$ can be expressed as the difference between two numbers less than $p(n)$ (not proving this but feels obvious), which both then factor.

Comment: Yes, but I've shown a small regular pattern in how to pick those numbers.  Perhaps the pattern continues?